# "make" doesn't find an installed library

Tags: debian, compiling, c, libraries

I am attempting to use make to compile `purple-facebook`, a plugin for `pidgin`.

It requires `json-glib`, which I have installed, but whenever I attempt to compile, it returns

```
fatal error: json-glib/json-glib.h: No such file or directory.
```

I've tried creating a symlink in `/usr/include` named `json-glib` linking to `json-glib-1.0`, but this results in it repeatedly outputting

```
gcc: warning: /var/cache/apt/archives/libjson-glib-1.0-0-dbg_1.0.2-1_armhf.deb: linker input file unused because linking not done.
```

I'm running Raspbian, a distro based on Debian. What can I do to get this thing to compile?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Rasbian user, but I'm assuming that you've just installed the JSON GLib *libraries*.  You also need the header files.  These are available in the `json-glib-dev` package.

As a general piece of advice:  If you find yourself moving things (libraries, binaries) around as root, or creating symlinks here and there, then it is highly likely that you're doing something wrong and that there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: I have those installed; still does not work. If it makes any difference, this is ARM.

Comment: @Precipitato The architecture makes no difference. It doesn't even make a difference that you're on Rasbian rather than OS X or Minix if you have all prerequisites installed, as far as I know. Update your question with relevant information about how you invoke `make` and if you ran a `configure` script or similar, what flags you passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Install the package [`libjson-glib-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libjson-glib-dev). It and its dependencies contain the files you need.

`json-glib/json-glib.h` is under `/usr/include/json-glib-1.0`. so the symbolic link you created is not useful. Remove it (it may confuse `configure` scripts). To get the compiler to search for header files under `/usr/include/json-glib-1.0`, you need to pass the option `-I /usr/include/json-glib-1.0`. But don't do that manually: call [`pkg-config`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config), which includes this and other necessary options. You need to ensure that the flags passed to the C compiler include `` `pkg-config --cflags json-glib-1.0` ``, and the link flags include `` `pkg-config --libs json-glib-1.0` ``.

Running `./autogen.sh` should generate makefiles with the appropriate options. If you ran it before you had all the required libraries installed, run `./configure` again; this will call `pkg-config` with the appropriate options and generate a new `Makefile`. Then type `make` to build.

To build the Debian package, installing the dependencies and then running `dpkg-buildpackage` should be enough (at least under jessie, I haven't checked if the requisite libraries exist in wheezy). If that doesn't work, copy-paste all the commands you ran and their full output.